# Can I control uploading something to staging and swap it in my code?

Tags: azure

I have a game site on Azure Cloud and I want to upload all games on the my management panel and I want to ability publish to test environment on staging and after swap it to production.
So In this situation , Can I control uploading to staging and swap it to real/live like azure management panel in my code ?

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. It would be helpful to see some code (even pseudocode) that shows what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I have game site on cloud and I upload all games via site's management panel to azure storage.In this time , I want to give to ability test to uploaded games for site's editor or admin , for example when he upload a game , he can test it on staging and when he click to activate button , uploaded game can be on production. So       maybe I can do it with change a boolean column value on production but I want to learn the best way for solve it so Is it possible control swap in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Windows Azure Management API for Hosted Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460812.aspx). You can upload a hosted service to a staging slot and later perform a VIP swap with an existing production environment in the same hosted service.

Just as an idea: If you want to host multiple games inside a single hosted service, you might want to think about uploading the newest versions into a blob storage and load them to your hosted service on demand.